# Green wood in beer

Tags: beer, ingredients, wood

I was wondering if I can make some post-christmas beer out of the christmas tree (Norway Spruce).

So my question is, does wood have to be dried in order to use it for flavoring or can I use green wood?

When should I add the wood in this case?

I was thinking to make a IPA with "piney" hops. (probably simcoe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For spruce flavored beers you don't use the wood.  You use the fresh lighter green tips that come out in springtime.  Its the new growth that is more aromatic and doesn't contain as much of the resins as the woody parts.
As far as using your spruce christmas tree, I think you are out of luck.

Comment: That's a shame. So, do you mean that green wood can't be used or that it would just be better with the fresh tips. I would sort of like to try anyways just for the fun of it, but not sure how to add the wood in that case.

Answer (score 3):

My concern with using green wood from a fir tree would be the high amount of sap. Also not sure about this but as far as flavor I think that you would get a better hint of what your looking for by using the needles themselves. I know of a few microbrewers who have made things like spruce beers by adding the needles in, just a thought.

Comment: I just realized I wrote the wrong tree. We have the "Norway spruce" and its sap is eatable.